# Bracket Operator Applied to Integer

Tags: c++, brackets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C arrays why is this true? a[5] == 5[a]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a)

I came about a piece of code that indexed into a string literal this way:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << 1["52"] << endl;
    cout << 0["52"] << endl;
}
```

I tried searching, but you can imagine the search terms bringing up unrelated topics. Can anyone explain how this works?

I realized it probably works with any pointer, so I tested this too:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[2]; a[0] = 22; a[1] = 600; 

    cout << 1[a] << endl;
    cout << 0[a] << endl;
}
```

Comment: [One of the top C++ questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a)

Comment: Apologies! I couldn't find it while searching. Is there a way to shut my question down?

Comment: @user904963, It'll probably be closed as a dupe soon, offering more search terms to redirect people to that one.